# How can I access (read/write) a mesh object's index vi Python?

Tags: python, objects

I would like to retrieve from python the index of an object -- the same index that you get when using an `Object info` node in shader nodes.

I have a reference to the object, but I don't see any attribute named index, or any function that returns it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access to the *Object Index* by using `pass_index` property.

Example code:

```
# reference to object
obj = bpy.data.objects['ObjectName']

# get object pass index
obj_index = obj.pass_index

# set object pass index
obj.pass_index = 1
```

Comment: Is the `pass_index` the same as the object index? I just tested this with two cubes (`Cube` and `Cube.001`), and `bpy.data.objects["Cube"].pass_index` and `bpy.data.objects["Cube.001"].pass_index` both have the same value of `0`. I see that I can manually update the `pass_index` value of one, and it does not affect the other, but I thought this index was unique for each object.

Comment: Yes, it's the same idea. In Blender you can set a unique number which refers to the Object Index, and that number is the Pass Index. The output socket "Object Index" - in the "Object Info" node - refers exactly to that number.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/nodes/types/input/object_info.html

```
bpy.context.object.pass_index
```